# Adding Keyboard input to Directories

Tags: python, input

I want to create a directory but I also want to add Keyboard input. Specifically, I want the user to chose the directory name, and location, and then it displays the name and location that the user entered.

Directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

# Create a directory that the user choses when and where
os.mkdir()
```

Keyboard Input:

```
filename = raw_input('Filename:')
print('You Entered the Filename:'), filename
```

**Figured it out!!!!!**

Thanks everyone but I figured it out!

```
    import os

    filename = raw_input('Enter Filename:')
    os.mkdir(filename)
    print('Filename Entered'), filename
```

Comment: Great! And what is your actual problem ?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to post on a site like http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.curdir
'.'
>>> filename = raw_input('Filename:')
Filename:mydir
>>> os.mkdir(filename)
>>> os.listdir(os.curdir)
['mydir']
```